# How can I make Siri's geo-fenced reminders wait until I actually arrive?

Tags: iphone, ios, siri, geolocation, reminders

I'm walking my dog and tell Siri, "When I get home, remind me to take out the trash." It sets up a reminder keyed to my arrival at a location, my home address. So far so good, but the reminder actually goes off when I'm still about a block from home. By the time I actually get home, I've forgotten all about it.

Is there any way to make Siri/Reminders more accurately assess whether I've arrived or not?

Comment: I don't think there is, but what I do when a geofenced reminder goes off is snooze it.

Comment: same problem here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have precise range control over geo fenced reminders with non iBeacon input. Both GPS and WiFi and cell tower location can trigger locations a good block or more away from a precise location.

Until you have iBeacon hardware or software set up, you can snooze that reminder, set a follow on time based reminder or change the original reminder to go off time rather than proximity.

The best you could do is offset the home location to coordinates several hundred feet away from where you typically approach and keep the same default 100m/330ft radius that iOS lets you make larger, but not smaller on iOS 7.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I want to be reminded to start my workout tracking app at the ice skating rink, but always get reminded before I get there.

It's a hack, but works if you will know which direction you'll arrive from. I set the location to be behind where I want to arrive and increase the radius to just where my intended location is. You will have to test the radius and adjust if it's not going off.

It would be nice if I could be reminded 15 minutes after arriving.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to change the location radius per reminder.

See the follow page http://forums.imore.com/guides-how-articles/262696-guide-how-set-location-based-reminder-ios-7-reminders-app.html

step 10

If you set a named location it should work.  something like "home"

Comment: The location radius defaults to the smallest available setting (for me, 328ft). You can use this technique to make the radius larger but not smaller.

Comment: Echoing @Robert—328 ft. is all I can do as well.  Also, johmicd, on Ask Different we prefer answers that stand alone.  Referring to a link is great for further information, but you should explain the required steps in your answer as well.

Comment: Changing radius is very cool if you want the reminder to fire sooner on arrival or later on departure, but won't help in this case where the OP wants a smaller arrival radius, not a larger one.